# C program to print every 5 seconds and show total time when we exit

Tags: c

The program should print to the screen every 5 seconds and state "alive at %d milliseconds\n".  When the user types in `<Control><A>` for the polling program or `<Control><C>` for the interrupt version, the program should stop and output:

`program terminated by user.   Total time is %d milliseconds %d seconds\n`.

My Program:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t print_flag = false;

void handle_alarm( int sig ) {
  print_flag = true;
}


int main() {
    struct timeval start, stop;
    double secs = 0;
    char key_press;
    char input_key;
    int ascii_value;
    float time_taken;
    clock_t t;
    t = clock();

    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

    signal( SIGALRM, handle_alarm );
    alarm( 5 ); 

    for (;;) {


      if ( print_flag ) {
        print_flag = false;
        alarm( 5 );
        gettimeofday(&stop, NULL);
        secs = (double)(stop.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1000000 + (double)(stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000;
        printf("Alive at %f ms \n",secs);
        input_key=getchar();
        ascii_value=input_key;
        if(ascii_value==1) {
          t = clock() - t;
          time_taken = ((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // in seconds
          printf("total time taken= %f sec", time_taken);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I want the program to run continuously but when I press ctrl a it should terminate. The program prints "Alive at 5000.000 ms and stops printing. The program prints infinitely every 5 seconds if I don't add the code for terminating using ctrl A. How to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

When you ask for input in this way, you are using synchronous blocking I/O.  The process hangs until input is given.  If you wish for your program to continue functioning while waiting for input you need to delve into asynchronous non-blocking I/O.  Look up the select() function

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Waiting-for-I_002fO.html

Answer (score 0):

After you do `print_flag = false;` in the `for` loop, you never set `print_flag` back to `true` again. Hence, the code in the `if ( print_flag )` block is executed only once.

> How to make it work?

To make it work, you need to set `print_flag` to `true` before you check whether it is true.

Comment: "*you never set `print_flag` back to `true` again*" this is done by the signal handler.

Comment: @alk printing `print_flag` inside the loop shows `0` every time.